# Why is Arabic an official langauage of the “Asian Football Confederation”

Tags: football, terminology

AFC has two official languages - English and Arabic.

> The official languages of the AFC shall be English and Arabic. In the
> event of any differences in any interpretation, the English text shall
> prevail. - [AFC](https://www.fam.org.my/sites/default/files/downloads/afc_statutes_2015_final.pdf)

What is the reason that Arabic is an Official Language of AFC?

Comment: There are a lot of countries in Asia where a lot of people talk Arabic. I am more surprised that there is no more official languages from Asia (Japanese, Hindu, Chinese, Korean). After all, it is Asian Football Confederation.

Comment: Arabic is the only official language of any country in Asia that is spoken in many countries (the only one I can think of). That may have had something to do with this, but I suspect politics must've been a reason too.

Comment: @alamoot  Farsi(Persian), Pashto, Urdo, Chinese are spoken in more than two countries

Comment: Arabic is spoken in 10+ countries in Asia, big difference